# Crossing complex and non uniform genomes?

Tags: genetic-algorithms

I've been tinkering with an artificial life simulator, critterding for many years and lately ive been branching the project and adding fitness functions.

Im still quiet new to genetic algorithms and currently critters in the simulation have very complex and different sized dna files which i want to be able to cross, currently they can only reproduce asexually and evolve purely through mutation.

For example, thier genome consists of:
Box part dimensions
Joint locations and angle constraints which connect those boxes
And a list of neurons, thier properties and synaptic connections

The number of boxes and thier joints can change by mutation as well as the number of neurons and synaptic connections and so im having a hard time trying to think up a crossover approach which can handle these variables.

So my question is, can anyone point me in the right direction for research material or give me insight into handling such dna structures for crossing?